# How to define highlight-able, clickable custom objects in libgdx (Risk game)

Tags: java, libgdx

I am making a game similar to Risk and struggling to find a way to implement the interaction with countries.

The basic idea is to create custom objects that are not rectangular and be able to change their colour by clicking them, highlight them with mouseover, or as the game progresses.

How would I go about having highlight-able countries that can be selected? The problem with sprites is their bounding boxes are rectangular, and if I define Box2D vertices and make polygons it gets really messy. Also, there are a lot of countries so a lot of the platformer style solutions don't fit.

How should I also change the colours of what is selected? Would it be best to have an individual sprite for every country and keep switching between them or is there a better way?

Comment: Normally one makes a "mask" for the sprite so that it can have a non-rectangular outline.  There's lots of techniques.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use polygons like you tried but I wonder why and what you mean it got messy. There are [tools](https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor) out there that let you draw vertices over a image and let you export that. You probably need to clean up the data a bit and import it into your app. It's also not very hard to make such an app yourself, have it import your image and start drawing and export to your favorite format. The more detailed you draw your polygons the more detail you get in your.

Perhaps an easier solution would be to use the opacity of each image of a country. Each country gets it's own image and you need to overlap the bounding rectangles to line them all up. When your mouse is hovering over one or more of these bounding boxes you check if the mouse is over a transparent pixel. If it is transparent you are obviously not hovering over the actual country. Some things to consider:

- I would create the game in a pixel perfect manner so each pixel of your images is translated to a single pixel of the screen your outputting to.
- To align your whole map I would create one big world map in your drawing application. Then save each country but remain the canvas size of the complete map. When packing these images with the LibGDX `TexturePacker` remove the whitespace (transparent pixels) and you will get an offset in your atlas. You can use this offset for each country to line them up and save precious texture space by removing all that whitespace.
- Always check for a simple collision first before diving in deeper.
- If you want to have "hover" functionality then don't do `pixmap = texture.getTextureData().consumePixmap()` each update since it's rather expensive. You might be better off creating your own 2D boolean array that represents the clickable area when you initialize the country object.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think the reason it got messy was because I was defining the polygons manually with coordinates and such but I think it might be ok if I use the tool you linked. Have you got any ideas for changing the texture when a click is detected inside the country? Or should I simply store each country in different states in a big set of textures and switch between them?

Comment: @ParJar Plenty of ideas. If the countries are actually clickable you could use Scene2D and extend from a `Button` or `ImageButton` the functionality for over, pressed and a listener to register clicks is already there. Otherwise just creating a couple of states like you mentioned sound fine.

Comment: If I were to implement the countries as imagebuttons is it possible to apply the polygon from the physicseditor as its bounding box to detect clicks?

Comment: nvm I've figured out how to create some accurate Box2D bodies to go underneath a texture, it's mostly switching the texture now